# R: Creating a matrix with loops/apply (Original code Fortran)

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, fortran, apply

Any help appreciated, I have been struggling with this problem far too long today, and I hope a fresh pair of eyes and set of braincells can help. Suggestions on how to make the code more efficient will also be greatly appreciated.

I am in the process of rewriting a program from Fortran into R. The eventual matrix, once all the data comes in, will be bigger that 1000x1000.

The first element of the code looked like this:

```
allocate (S(nrecords))
do i=1,nrecords
    S(i)=ZZ(i,i)
  end do
```

which in R simply became this: `S<-diag(ZZ)` **nrecords in the example data = 10

The example dataset I am using consists of a 10x10 matrix ZZ:

```
167315  136626  138035  150376  137080  136561  139467  137161  151010  140947
136626  171188  139660  138286  138161  138709  139713  138422  138138  140265
138035  139660  170362  138202  138643  138168  140629  139121  137675  139288
150376  138286  138202  167354  138025  138029  140168  137797  144110  139955
137080  138161  138643  138025  168606  144637  140715  138636  142043  141936
136561  138709  138168  138029  144637  167756  140256  138348  140914  152011
139467  139713  140629  140168  140715  140256  172119  141704  140553  140769
137161  138422  139121  137797  138636  138348  141704  169635  137902  138752
151010  138138  137675  144110  142043  140914  140553  137902  169823  142444
140947  140265  139288  139955  141936  152011  140769  138752  142444  173183
```

so S is a vector containing the diagonal values.

I am stuck in translating this Fortran element though:

```
 allocate(D(nrecords,nrecords))
  sumD=0
do i=1,nrecords
   do j=1,nrecords
    D(i,j)=S(i)+S(j)-2*ZZ(i,j)
    sumD=sumD+D(i,j)
   end do
end do

       deallocate(ZZ)
sumD=sumD/(nrecords*nrecords)
```

I know that at the end of the day I am supposed to end up with another 10x10 matrix, where D1,1 will equal to 0, and D1,2 will be 65251. But between reading-up on for-loops, apply(), sapply() and tapply() I am rather lost and confused.

This is another element that has already been translated, and I wanted to base the fortran translation on this, but I think I have been staring at it too long, and I strongly suspect that there is a more efficient answer:

```
n <-6


sumA <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
   for (j in 1:n) {
  sumA <- sumA+A[i,j]
              }
            }

sumA2 <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
   for (j in 1:n) {
  sumA2 <- sumA2+A[i,j]^2
                 }
            }
```

with the corresponding fortran:

```
 sumA2=0.0;sumA=0.0
     do i=1,nrecords
      do j=1,nrecords
        if(A(i,j) > 0.0) then
           sumA2=sumA2+(A(i,j)*A(i,j))
           sumA=sumA+A(i,j)
        end if
      end do
    end do



 sumMMA=0.0;sumZZ=0.0
  do i=1,nrecords
   do j=1,nrecords
    sumMMA=sumMMA+(ZZ(i,j)*A(i,j))
   sumZZ=sumZZ+ZZ(i,j)  !this will not work using the sum(ZZ) function
  end do
 end do
```

Matrix A is simply

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0.75    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0.5 0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0.75    0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `apply` functions is to improve readability.  If you don't understand them you don't need to use them.  They are more or less wrappers for `for` loops.  In your case, you can almost translate your code verbatim.

R

```
nrecords <- 10
ZZ <- as.matrix(read.table(header=F, text='
167315  136626  138035  150376  137080  136561  139467  137161  151010  140947
136626  171188  139660  138286  138161  138709  139713  138422  138138  140265
138035  139660  170362  138202  138643  138168  140629  139121  137675  139288
150376  138286  138202  167354  138025  138029  140168  137797  144110  139955
137080  138161  138643  138025  168606  144637  140715  138636  142043  141936
136561  138709  138168  138029  144637  167756  140256  138348  140914  152011
139467  139713  140629  140168  140715  140256  172119  141704  140553  140769
137161  138422  139121  137797  138636  138348  141704  169635  137902  138752
151010  138138  137675  144110  142043  140914  140553  137902  169823  142444
140947  140265  139288  139955  141936  152011  140769  138752  142444  173183
                 '))

S <- diag(ZZ)
```

Fortran

```
 allocate(D(nrecords,nrecords))
  sumD=0
do i=1,nrecords
   do j=1,nrecords
    D(i,j)=S(i)+S(j)-2*ZZ(i,j)
    sumD=sumD+D(i,j)
   end do
end do

       deallocate(ZZ)
sumD=sumD/(nrecords*nrecords)
```

R

```
D <- matrix(0, nrecords, nrecords)
sumD = 0
for(i in 1:nrecords){
  for(j in 1:nrecords){
    D[i,j] = S[i] + S[j] - 2*ZZ[i,j]
    sumD = sumD + D[i,j]
  }
}
sumD = sumD/(nrecords*nrecords)
```

Fortran

```
do i=1,nrecords
  do j=1,nrecords
    if(A(i,j) > 0.0) then
       sumA2=sumA2+(A(i,j)*A(i,j))
       sumA=sumA+A(i,j)
    end if
  end do
end do    

sumMMA=0.0;sumZZ=0.0
  do i=1,nrecords
   do j=1,nrecords
    sumMMA=sumMMA+(ZZ(i,j)*A(i,j))
   sumZZ=sumZZ+ZZ(i,j)  !this will not work using the sum(ZZ) function
  end do
 end do
```

R

```
A <- matrix(0, nrecords, nrecords)
diag(A) <- c(1,.75,1,1,1,.5,.75,1,1,1)

sumA2 = 0
sumA = 0
for(i in 1:nrecords){
  for(j in 1:nrecords){
    if(A[i,j] > 0){
      sumA2=sumA2+(A[i,j]*A[i,j])
      sumA = sumA+A[i,j]
    }
  }
}

sumMMA=0
sumZZ=0
for(i in 1:nrecords){
  for(j in 1:nrecords){
    sumMMa=sumMMA+(ZZ[i,j]*A[i,j])
    sumZZ=sumZZ+ZZ[i,j]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cdeterman! I have been told that I try to overcomplicate things too much, I did not realize the answer could be so simple :)